Function to output array in itemize
I tried to create a single function that would output inline and function return arrays represented as clists in itemize. I didn't succeed to create such function, only separate ones.
This function outputs function arrays:
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\ItemizeClist{m}
{
    \int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int

    \begin{itemize}
    \clist_map_inline:Nn {#1}
    {
        \item \str_lowercase:n {##1}

        \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
        \int_compare:nNnTF { \l_tmpa_int } = { \clist_count:N {#1} }
        {
            .
        }
        {
            ;
        }
    }
    \end{itemize}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\Tasks
{%
    {Mur mur},%
    {Wof wof}%
}

\begin{document}

\ItemizeClist{\Tasks}

\end{document}

This function outputs inline arrays:
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\ItemizeClist{m}
{
    \int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int

    \begin{itemize}
    \clist_map_inline:nn {#1}
    {
        \item \str_lowercase:n {##1}

        \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
        \int_compare:nNnTF { \l_tmpa_int } = { \clist_count:n {#1} }
        {
            .
        }
        {
            ;
        }
    }
    \end{itemize}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ItemizeClist
{%
    {Text Text},%
    {Boop Boop}%
}

\end{document}

Need to join these functions into one.

\item \str_lowercase:n {##1 note that str functions produce detokenized strings (like string or \detokenize) which are unsuitable for typesetting (although work if you are restricting to using ascii only. You should use the \text_ module functions for language senitive lowercasing suitable for printing. (oh egreg said same,  but can't hurt to say it twice)

That's my solution:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\ItemizeClist{s m}
{
    \ifdefmacro{#2}
    {
        \clist_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_clist {#2}
    }
    {
        \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#2}
    }

    \int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int

    \begin{itemize}
        \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist 
        {
            \item
            
            \IfBooleanTF {#1}
            {
                ##1
            }
            {
                \MakeLowercase{##1}
                
                \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
                \int_compare:nNnTF { \l_tmpa_int } = { \clist_count:N \l_tmpa_clist }
                {
                    .
                }
                {
                    ;
                }
            }
        }
    \end{itemize}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\Tasks
{%
    {Beop beop},%
    {Wof wof}%
}

\begin{document}

\ItemizeClist{\Tasks}

\ItemizeClist{ {Mur, mur}, {Bop, bop} }

\end{document}

Additionally, added star variant. You can specify what I should correct.

A macro defined with \newcommand is not quite the same as a clist.
The problem fits in a line of list management questions in the last few days. Here I propose to internally use sequences, rather than clists.
Your lists/sequences will be called by name and you can have as many of them as you like. Appending items can be added easily.
The idea here is to map the given sequence so as to add the preprocessing instruction (you seem to want \MakeLowercase) and then to deliver the sequence after a leading \item, with ;\item in between items and a period at the end.
With \ItemizeList* we instruct to use the given data and not a named list.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\NewList}{mm}
 {
  \seq_new:c { l_intolight_list_#1_seq }
  \seq_set_from_clist:cn { l_intolight_list_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__intolight_list_temp_seq
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_map:NNn { Ncn }

\NewDocumentCommand\ItemizeList{s O{\use:n} m}
 {
  \begin{itemize}
  \IfBooleanTF { #1 }
   {% use the data as given
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #3 }
    \seq_set_map:NNn \l__intolight_list_temp_seq \l_tmpa_seq { #2{##1} }
   }
   {% use a named list
    \seq_set_map:Ncn \l__intolight_list_temp_seq { l_intolight_list_#3_seq } { #2{##1} }
   }
  \item \seq_use:Nn \l__intolight_list_temp_seq { ; \item } .
  \end{itemize}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewList{Tasks}
 {
  Mur mur,
  {Wof, wof}
 }

\begin{document}

First we produce the itemized list with lowercased item
\ItemizeList[\MakeLowercase]{Tasks}

Next we produce the itemized list as is
\ItemizeList{Tasks}

First we produce the itemized list with lowercased item
\ItemizeList*[\MakeLowercase]{Mur mur, Wof wof}

Next we produce the itemized list as is
\ItemizeList*{Mur mur, Wof wof}

\end{document}


A few notes.
Using \NewExpandableDocumentCommand is not a magic wand that makes expandable what isn't. Doing assignments is never an expandable business.
Don't use \str_lowercase:n on text that's supposed to be printed. Try your code with naïve to see why.
Braces around the list items are only necessary if the item contains a comma. Protecting endlines after the comma separators isn't needed: \seq_set_from_clist:Nn will ignore them along with leading or trailing spaces.

If you really want to pursue the strategy of \newcommand (you shouldn't, it's bad syntax), here's how.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\ItemizeList{O{\use:n} m}
 {
  \begin{itemize}
  \seq_clear:N \l__intolight_list_temp_seq
  \bool_lazy_and:nnTF { \tl_if_single_p:n { #2 } } { \token_if_cs_p:N #2 }
   {% #2 is a cs
    \__intolight_list_process:nV {#1} #2
   }
   {% #2 is not a cs
    \__intolight_list_process:nn {#1} {#2}
   }
  \item \seq_use:Nn \l__intolight_list_out_seq { ; \item } .
  \end{itemize}
 }

\seq_new:N \l__intolight_list_temp_seq
\seq_new:N \l__intolight_list_out_seq
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__intolight_list_process:nn
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__intolight_list_temp_seq {#2}
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l__intolight_list_out_seq \l__intolight_list_temp_seq { #1{##1} }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__intolight_list_process:nn { nV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\Tasks}
 {
  Mur mur,
  {Wof, wof}
 }

\begin{document}

First we produce the itemized list with lowercased item
\ItemizeList[\MakeLowercase]{\Tasks}

Next we produce the itemized list as is
\ItemizeList{\Tasks}

First we produce the itemized list with lowercased item
\ItemizeList[\MakeLowercase]{Mur mur, Wof wof}

Next we produce the itemized list as is
\ItemizeList{Mur mur, Wof wof}

\end{document}

The output is the same as before.

I want to know what's a problem with passing clist as newcommand and why seq instead of clist in algorithm? Also, I would like that determination of condition branch did not occur by the presence of star.

@Intolighter Sequences are more efficient than clists. About using \newcommand I simply find it awkward. What's the problem with the *? You might branch by examining the argument and, if it's a single word, assume it is a list name.

More efficient means faster?

@Intolighter Exactly.
